# How to set callback and pass node.js module functions variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

I am trying to pass customerId, customerDescription, and customerEmail into createCustomerProfile, which is imported from a separate module.

The callback variable was default by the original author, and I am trying to extend the module to take these extra variables.

Can I pass them in somehow?  I tried using the bind function, but it kept throwing errors, and I'm not sure how to proceed.  I had a similar problem before and used object literal syntax to pass in JSON-like data, but the callback variable is throwing me off.

index.js

```
const profiles = require('./authorize-net/lib/init-profile.js');
profiles.createCustomerProfile(function() {
  console.log('call back');
});
```

init-profile.js

```
// require some stuff...

function createCustomerProfile(callback, customerId, customerDescription, customerEmail) {

let cardNumber = '4242424242424242';
let cardExp = '0822';

// set some properties...

let customerProfileType = new ApiContracts.CustomerProfileType();
customerProfileType.setMerchantCustomerId(customerId);
customerProfileType.setDescription(customerDescription);
customerProfileType.setEmail(customerEmail);
customerProfileType.setPaymentProfiles(paymentProfilesList);

let ctrl = new ApiControllers.CreateCustomerProfileController(createRequest.getJSON());

ctrl.execute(function(){

    let apiResponse = ctrl.getResponse();

    let response = new ApiContracts.CreateCustomerProfileResponse(apiResponse);

    callback(response);
});
}

if (require.main === module) {
  createCustomerProfile(function(){
    console.log('createCustomerProfile call complete.');
  });
}

module.exports.createCustomerProfile = createCustomerProfile;
```

Answer (score 0):

The callback comes last in the list of parameters.

Comment: Is the nested function in ```index.js``` passed in as the callback?

Comment: And should I be using ```bind```?